# How to play system sound in Delphi FireMonkey XE4?

Tags: delphi, audio, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I want to play system sound in both Windows and MAC OS X. To play sound in Windows used *something* like this:

```
PlaySound('C:\Windows\Media\Windows Default.wav', 0, SND_FILENAME + SND_ASYNC);
```

I am sure I have to use TMediaPlayer.

Comment: In Windows **system** sound has to be played as `PlaySound('SystemStart', 0, SND_ALIAS)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, you can use the [TMediaPlayer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer) component, documentation clearly states :

> TMediaPlayer playbacks audio files and the audio component of a video
>   file.
>
> To specify the media file to be played by the current TMediaPlayer,
>   set the FileName property. The file name **must include** the path of the
>   file, so it can be localized on the memory, and the extension. Call
>   the **Play** and **Stop** methods to start playing a media file, or to stop or
>   pause a running media file. The current position is specified through
>   the CurrentTime property.
>
> TMediaPlayer also exposes media file
>   properties such as Duration, VideoSize, Volume or State.

Regarding the supported file formats [(TMediaCodecManager)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Media.TMediaCodecManager).

The documentation states the following:

> Use TMediaCodecManager to access, manage, and register codecs to be
>   used when playing media files.
>
> The supported media files formats are the native formats for each
>   platform:
>
> **For Windows:**
>      Audio formats: .wma, .mp3, .wav
>      Video formats: .avi,.wmv
>
> **For Mac OS/iOS:**
>    Audio formats: .mp3, .caf
>    Video formats: .mov, .m4v, .mp4
>
> Using TMediaCodecManager, it is possible to register custom
>   media codecs to extend the audio/video feature support.

Quick example :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 MediaPlayer1.FileName := 'D:\test.mp3';
 MediaPlayer1.Play;
end;
```

You should be able to play mp3 files in Firemonkey across platforms but that is out of scope of this question.

Comment: Ahh, so, some `{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
WindowsPath
{$ELSE}
MacOSXPath
{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}` I though there is some `MediaPlayer1.FileName := TSound.SystemQuestion;` or something.

Comment: @PeterVonča I believe what he means is that he thought there would be constants pointing to the appropriate system sounds so that there would be no need for IFDEFs. What I'm confused about is "Note: In order to play an audio file on your iOS device using TMediaPlayer, use either of the following formats: .wav on Windows | .caf on iOS and Mac OS X" - what about playing MP3 or some more standard format?

Comment: @alcalde, TMediaPlayer accepts the default registered formats but you can add more via the TMediaCodecManager.

Comment: @alcalde, also, you can play mp3 files just fine, the documentation seems to be lacking or is incomplete for TMediaPlayer reference, however the TMEdiaCodecManager does state that you can play mp3 audio files and I have tested it.

Comment: `Function TForm1.PlaySound: Boolean;
Begin
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  MediaPlayer1.FileName := 'C:\Windows\Media\Windows Default.wav';
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF MACOS}
  MediaPlayer1.FileName := '/System/Library/Sounds/Sosumi.aiff';
{$ENDIF}
  if FileExists(MediaPlayer1.FileName) then
  begin
    MediaPlayer1.Play;
    Result := True;
  end
  else
    Result := False;
End;`