# Delphi Firemonkey sound tone

Tags: delphi, audio, firemonkey

In Delphi XE6/XE7 Firemonkey for both MSWINDOWS and MACOS,

how do I play a short tone of say frequency 700 and duration of a half second?

(Playing a system sound is too slow and code heavy for this application.)

Comment: See [How to play system sound in Delphi FireMonkey XE4?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18576772/576719).

Comment: `beep;` makes a sound ;)

Comment: Playing a system sound isn't that hard. But I could use an answer to my question. :)

Comment: Make an mp3 file with wanted frequency and use the TMediaPlayer to play the file. You can restrict the sound duration with settings in the mediaplayer.

Comment: Playing a system sound or playing an mp3 file is a bit too code heavy for what I'm looking for. Using TMediaPlayer for extremely short and fast tone generation would be a bit like wanting to draw a small filled rectangle and accomplishing it by loading and cropping a gif.